# Rails.application.assets_manifest.find_sources("#{params[:controller]}.js").any? crashes on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

in my application_layout.html.rb of my rails application I'm loading controller specific javascript:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] if Rails.application.assets_manifest.find_sources("#{params[:controller]}.js").any? %>
```

Which is working correctly until I deploy to Heroku. Than I get this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `find_asset' for nil:NilClass)
```

The same error I get when I try to call any method on the object returned from #find_sources.

**EDIT:**

```
<%= Rails.application.assets_manifest.find_sources("#{params[:controller]}.js") %>
```

returns `#&lt;Enumerator:0x007fda655a17b0&gt;`

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not work because there is a static manifest file in production and no in development (usually, it depends on environment config). You can create a helper method to do the check differently based on current environment configuration:

```
def asset_exist?(path)
  if Rails.configuration.assets.compile
    Rails.application.precompiled_assets.include? path
  else
    Rails.application.assets_manifest.assets[path].present?
  end
end
```

Please check [this issue](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/298#issuecomment-168927471) for more details.

Comment: Worked, dziekuje bardzo! :)  
And thanks for the explanation.